# Ansible use alias from shell module when bash_profile is sourced

Tags: shell, module, ansible, alias

So I have an issue while using Ansible and the shell module.
What I'm trying to do is use an alias which exist on my remote host, but when I try to use it in the shell module it says that this command doesn't exist.

Let's say that in my bash_profile I got this alias :

**alias test='cd /test/folder'**

What I do on Ansible is this :

```
- name: Task that need to use an alias from the remote host
  shell: |
    source /root/.bash_profile && test
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

But it doesn't work... it says that the command **test** doesn't exist.

I tried with this as an executable, but no luck :

```
 executable: /bin/bash -i
```

What I can confirm, is that the sourcing of the bash_profile is working well, because I did this command : `source /root/.bash_profile && alias` to test and and I saw my alias available.

I also tried that way, but still doesn't work :

```
shell: |
    source /root/.bash_profile 
    test
```

And last thing I tried is using the `eval` command like so, but still with no luck :

```
shell: |
    source /root/.bash_profile && eval test
```

I don't really what to try anymore... I just need to use an alias while executing the shell module, can anyone help me on this?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Snoobz, welcome to SO. I can't tell from your code if you really mean `test` or you're just anonymizing your question, but for sure do not try and create an alias named `test` as it's both a built-in and an on-disk binary; you will also get a lot further in your troubleshooting by turning on `xtrace` mode, via `shell: set -x; source /root/.bash_profile; whatever_your_alias_is`

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply. The alias named test is just for an example purpose. Of course the alias name that I try to use in my code is named differently. I will try to use the xtrace and report back.